# Calculate balance from received stock and issued stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

For your usual support, I have two tables and I need to get balance from the two of them.

The first table is used to store issued stock.

```
SELECT [ProductID],[ReferenceNumber],[Quantity],[IssuedDate],[CreatedDate]
  FROM [inventory].[dbo].[tblIssueStocks]
```

The second table is listed below and it stores received stock

```
SELECT TOP [ProductID],[Quantity],[RecieveDate],[CreatedDate]
  FROM [inventory].[dbo].[tblRecievedStocks]
```

Thank you for a prompt response.

Comment: Add sample table data, and it's expected result!

Comment: all columns has the same value on both table except quantity and date now i want to calculate stock in and stock out balance

Comment: @user3501084 . . . Sample data and desired results.  *You* understand the problem you are facing.  People "out here" don't.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. Have a go yourself. If it doesn't work come back with your code and error messages. SO has a handy guide to composing a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which I think will help you. There is also [this artical](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to provide good sample data. Finally I see you have several open questions. If the answers provided helped you; you should consider [accepting them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This rewards those that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the table `tblRecievedStocks` represents the products that entered your store while the table `tblIssueStocks` represents the products that left your store.

Supposing you need the number of each product that are currently in your store, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT          received.ProductID,
                SUM(NVL(received.Quantity, 0)) - SUM(NVL(issued.Quantity, 0)) AS CurrentBalance
FROM            tblRecievedStocks received
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblIssueStocks    issued
             ON received.ProductID = issued.ProductID
GROUP BY        received.ProductID
ORDER BY        received.ProductID;
```

Comment: I realize my answer is almost equal to the one JaydipJ posted just before I did. The only difference is the OUTER join which covers the products that have never been issued.

Comment: Yes, but SUM(NVL(issued.Quantity, 0)result is always multiplied by 2

Comment: Verify the contents of both tables. Maybe the same element (reception or issueing of a product) is entered twice.